# SharePoint 2010 - List "Variation Labels" does not exist at site with URL

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, error, variations

In SharePoint 2010 Enterprise I'm trying to visit the Variation Labels page at ".../_Layouts/VariationLabels.aspx".

When I load this page I'm confronted with the following error:

```
Error 
An unexpected error has occurred. 

Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation. 

Correlation ID: ac92d8e4-7454-4898-a4bf-f97e14ca612b 

Date and Time:
```

Next I search for this correlation ID in the ULS logs and find:

```
System.ArgumentException: List 'Variation Labels' does not exist
 at site with URL 'https://sharepoint.company.com'.   
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListCollection.GetListByName(String strListName, Boolean bThrowException)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPDataSourceView.GetList(SPContext context, SPWeb web, Guid listId, String listName)
```

Is anyone here familiar with this error and In how I should solve it?

Comment: could you please double check and make sure the Variation Labels exist in the site collection.

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE How can I verify if the Variation Labels exist in the Site Collection?

Answer (score 1):

you can try to fix variation label and here is the link how to do it:

```
stsadm -o variationsfixuptool 
          -url <absolute web URL> 
         [-fix] 
         [-scan] 
         [-spawn] 
         [-showrunningjobs] 
         [-recurse] 
         [-label <label to fix or spawn>]
```

http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2011/11/28/sharepoint-variations-the-complete-guide-part-11-variations-fixup-tool.aspx

Comment: When I run the command "stsadm -o variationsfixuptool -url https://sharepoint.company.com -scan", I receive the notification "SharePoint site https://sharepoint.company.com has no variations".

Comment: try to enable variation on root level. as showing in the following post. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/ec237c6c-5349-413b-b527-fbc06fc7d5c6/unable-to-create-site-hierarchy-for-any-variation-label

Answer (score 1):

In my case this error occurred since *non-default language* was selected during root site provision.

It seems `Variation labels` application page retrieves Variations List by its title and expects `Variation Labels` value.

**Solution**

Update Variations List title to `Variation Labels`. The below example demonstrates how to update Variations List title using CSOM.

### How to modify Variations List title using SharePoint CSOM

```
public class VariationsManager
{
    public static List GetLabelsList(ClientContext context)
    {
        var rootWeb = context.Site.RootWeb;
        context.Load(rootWeb, w => w.AllProperties);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
        var varLabelsListId = new Guid(rootWeb.AllProperties[VarLabelsListIdKey].ToString());
        return rootWeb.Lists.GetById(varLabelsListId);
    }


    private const string VarLabelsListIdKey = "_VarLabelsListId";
}



using (var ctx = new ClientContext(webUrl))
{

   var varList = VariationsManager.GetLabelsList(ctx);
   varList.Title = "Variation Labels";
   varList.Update();
   ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```